# Как сделать header() в условии if?

Tags: php

Есть форма. Обработчик находится на той же странице, если пользователь ввел информацию и нажал сохранить, то обработчик заносит значение в переменную, потом, если есть переменная(допустим $name), то нужно сделать переадресацию на страницу. Но `header` нельзя вставить туда, где до этого что то выводится. Rак поступить?

```
if (!empty($name))
{
  header("location: profile.php");
}
```

Comment: Зачем что-то выводить? Сначала проверяете, нет ли данных. Данных нет - показываете форму. Есть данные - выводите заголовок редиректа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header` надо высылать раньше, чем выведен хотя бы один символ.

Как вариант, сохраняйте вывод в буфер, пока все хедеры не будут переданы. [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) в помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Вы имеете ввиду такое?

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['email']) or isset($_SESSION['password'])){   // проверяем существует емаил или пароль пользователя

   $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
   mysql_select_db('elandb',$connect);

   $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND password='".$_SESSION['password']."'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 1){  // если в базе нет такого пользователя

      header("location:http://localhost/xampp/exam/register_author/index.php");

     }
}
else                        // если не существет
{
    header("location:http://localhost/xampp/exam/register_author/index.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать переадресацию на страницу с помощью javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    location.replace("страница");
</script>
```